# fetch rows where left join subquery is null (not found)

Tags: mysql

How to fetch rows where a joined subquery is null?

```
SELECT *
FROM bank_recon b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o.bank_recon_id
    FROM data_voucher_ocr_bank o
    LEFT JOIN data_voucher v ON v.id=o.data_voucher_id
    WHERE v.is_ocr_verified=1
    LIMIT 1
) s ON s.bank_recon_id=b.id
WHERE s IS NULL
```

## update

When using this query (the subquery) something is fetched depending on if `is_ocr_verified` is set or not

```
SELECT o.bank_recon_id
FROM data_voucher_ocr_bank o
LEFT JOIN data_voucher v ON v.id=o.data_voucher_id
WHERE v.is_ocr_verified=1 && o.bank_recon_id=320062
```

When using this query everything is fetched no matter what!?

```
SELECT b.txt, b.amount
FROM bank_recon b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o.bank_recon_id
    FROM data_voucher_ocr_bank o
    LEFT JOIN data_voucher v ON v.id=o.data_voucher_id
    WHERE v.is_ocr_verified=1
    LIMIT 1
) s ON s.bank_recon_id=b.id
WHERE b.id=320062 && s.bank_recon_id IS NULL
```

Comment: you need the WHERE filter on a column not a  delivered table alias.

Comment: Why use an anti join at all? I'd simply use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. These are much more readable. The `LEFT JOIN` inside your subquery should be `INNER JOIN` by the way (and your `WHERE` clause even turns it into an inner join implicitly).

Comment: @thorsten kettner could you give me an example?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner how to pass a variable into the `NOT EXISTS` clause?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner create an answer.. it works with `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 2):

Specify a column in your `WHERE` clause, not just the subquery.

```
WHERE s.bank_recon_id IS NULL
```

Comment: have tried it but it fetches all rows no matter if the subquery is found or not

Comment: @clarkk: Because this is not the only issue in your query. Your subquery selects one row. So you dismiss only the one bank_recon record that matches this row. You'd have to remove the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

An anti join (which is what you are trying to apply here) is a method we use when the straight-forward `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` have performance issues in a DBMS.

Provided `data_voucher_ocr_bank.bank_recon_id` cannot be null, we can use:

```
SELECT txt, amount
FROM bank_recon
WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT bank_recon_id
  FROM data_voucher_ocr_bank
  WHERE data_voucher_id IN (SELECT id FROM data_voucher WHERE is_ocr_verified = 1)
);
```

(Otherwise we'd add `AND bank_recon_id IS NOT NULL` or use `NOT EXISTS` instead.)